# Trying to push changes made in a local file (cloned from a GitHub branch) to that same branch through Gitbash?

Tags: github, push, branch, git-bash

command line and GitHub. Im having trouble trying to link a branch i made of a github repository to my gitbash so that i could push changes to that branch. I cloned the address of the branch in Github and used that address to make a local repository. Now im not sure if i push changes it would only affect the branch and not the main, because thats what happened the first time i cloned (i used the mains clone address that time). Could you show me what to do?

I tried this
$ git push origin

and i got this
src refspec does not match any

which says a branch with that name doesnt exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out by googling how to create a branch in gitbash, learned that you can use
`$ git checkout -b <branch-name>`
to create a branch then use push to upstream to select the branch in the remote repository ie
`$ git push –set-upstream origin <new-branch>`
In the case that you only want to push to the branch you cloned, just set the name `<new-branch>` to the name it has on the github website

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).